# Does the result of a continuation have to be the final result?

Tags: haskell, continuations

To produce the final result from a `Cont r a`  type, you need to pass it to `runCont` and provide a continuation of type `(a -> r)`:

```
runCont :: Cont r a -> (a -> r) -> r
```

The signature only tells us, that the the return value of the continuation must have the same **type** `r` as the final result, but it doesn't tell us, that the return **value** of the continuation must be the final result.

I can actually do some further processing of `r` before returning the final result. Here I prepend a String to the result:

```
cnt :: Num p => p -> Cont String p
cnt x = let f k = "result=" ++ k (x+1)
        in cont f

λ> runCont (cnt 1) show
"result=2"

λ> runCont (cnt 1) (flip take "Hello")
"result=He"
```

However, the continuation is often said to be *the rest of the computation*. This suggests its return value undergoes no further processing within `Cont` and *is* the final result.

I have a feeling, that directly returning that `r` value, gives me a tail call and least restricts the possible types of `r`, but I'm not sure if this is correct, not whether this is the whole story.

- Is further processing of the return value of a continuation something to be avoided or is it perfectly normal?
- Does further processing of `r` have any drawbacks, or can it even break things?
- Are there additional things to consider when using the `ContT` monad transformer?

Comment: You might prefer [`Codensity`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-5.1/docs/Control-Monad-Codensity.html#t:Codensity) [`Identity`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html#t:Identity), which prevents those sorts of shenanigans.

Comment: @Carl I wouldn't call them *shenanigans*, really. As per my comment in the linked question, this has uses. I'm not well-versed in this stuff, but what I think happened here is that `Codensity` represents a "weak" form of continuations, `SCont f r a = (a -> r) -> f` represents a very "powerful" sort, and we have `Cont r a = (a -> r) -> r` as a middle ground. `Codensity` prohibits "post-processing", `SCont` allows it in its full glory (but we don't use it because Haskell doesn't have syntax for it), and `Cont` has it in a crippled form that we *do* have a syntax for.

Comment: @HTNW `Codensity m` doesn't prevent post-processing, exactly.  You can still add arbitrary `m` effects.  You have to go to `Codensity Identity` to prevent all post-processing, because `Identity` doesn't have any effects.